# CentOS 8, SSSD, LDAP and yubikey PIV authentication problem

Tags: centos, openldap, sssd, yubikey

Trying to set up the following

Authentication with Yubikey (PIV) with LDAP.

Already got the authentication with Yubikey and local users working with SSSD. Also got the LDAP working with SSSD but not the things together. Trying different guides and looked at the logs `/var/log/sssd/sssd*` many hours without success.

Running a clean CentOS8 with Gnome. No hardening applied at the moment. SELinux is in permissive mode.

I think the problem is that the mapping between the Certificate on the yubikey and the users in LDAP not working.

I do see in the `sssd_pam.log` that the `gdm-password` is used but should be `gdm-smartcard`? Clueless...

The auth profile: sssd, with "with-smartcard" active

in the `sssd.conf`:

```
pam_cert_auth = True

ldap_user_certificate = UserCertificate;binary
```

Do you have to the mapping in somehow? When doing with local users you had to do:

```
[certmap/domain/username]<br>
matchrule = \<subject>.*CN=username.\*
```

Also tried adding the public certificate on yubikey to the userCertificate in ldap but no change.

Any ideas?